# Installing TinyMCE plugins on Drupal 7 with the WYSIWYG module

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I using Drupal 7 and the WYSIWYG module and the TinyMCE (3.4.2) plugin.
I want to install a plugin for TinyMCE.

I placed the plugin folder in the right directory.

```
sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins
```

However, the plugin doesn't show up in my configuration checkboxes for the WYSIWYG configuration.  What else do I need to do to enable a contributed plugin?

Answer (score 5):

You need to inform the WYSIWYG module that you've installed a plugin, it won't know it's there otherwise. It will involve writing a small custom module.

Have a look in the `wysiwyg.api.php` and `wysiwyg.api.js` files included in the root of the  WYSIWYG module folder; there are examples and very good documentation explaining exactly what you need to do.

The most important (perhaps only) hook you'll need to implement is `hook_wysiwyg_plugin()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I see what you are talking about, however I am not sure where to place the hook_wysiwyg_plugin()
I put it in the wysiwyg.api.php file, however that didn't do anything.

Comment: You need to put that code in a custom module (see the [Module Developer's Guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules)). If your module name is `MYMODULE` then the hook name you want will be `MYMODULE_wysiwyg_plugin()`

Comment: Thanks, however, it's not a Drupal Module, but a TinyMCE plugin. http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3151211&group_id=103281&atid=738747

Comment: Yep, you need to write a custom Drupal module to inform WYSIWYG about the TinyMCE plugin so it knows to allow you to configure it from the WYSIWYG settings forms.